# SQL Query where condition while performing update query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Team, i have three table Table1 , Table2 and TableComment. I just want to update data from Table2 to Table1 if the Table2 data matches with three column data of TableComment. In the below example the first row from Table2 should update in Table1 and second row should not update.

Table1

```
TID Category    Sub Category    Code
123456  1. AAAAA    1.1 First   FF1
234567          
345678          
124123          
123413          
635464
```

Table2

```
TID Category    Sub Category    Code
123456  1. AAAAA    1.1 First   FF1
234567  1. AAAAA    2.1 First   FS1
```

Table comments

```
Category    Sub Category    Code
1. AAAAA    1.1 First   FF1
1. AAAAA    1.1 First   FF2
1. AAAAA    1.1 First   FF3
1. AAAAA    1.2 Second  FS1
1. AAAAA    1.2 Second  FS2
1. AAAAA    1.2 Second  FS3
1. AAAAA    1.3 Third   FT1
1. AAAAA    1.3 Third   FT2
1. AAAAA    1.3 Third   FT3
2. BBBBB    2.1 First   SF1
2. BBBBB    2.1 First   SF2
2. BBBBB    2.1 First   SF3
2. BBBBB    2.2 Second  SS1
2. BBBBB    2.2 Second  SS2
2. BBBBB    2.2 Second  SS3
2. BBBBB    2.3 Third   ST1
2. BBBBB    2.3 Third   ST2
2. BBBBB    2.3 Third   ST3
```

Sample Code

```
UPDATE (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.TID = Table2.TID) INNER JOIN TableComment 
ON Table2.Category = TableComment.Category and 
Table2.[Sub Category] = TableComment.[Sub Category] and
Table2.[Code] = TableComment.[Code]
SET Table1.Category = Table2.Category and 
Table1.[Sub Category] = Table2.[Sub Category] and
Table1.[Code] = Table2.[Code]
```

Comment: Please post your sample code.

Comment: Use an `INNER JOIN` to find the rows that match, and use that in your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @Remou updated the query please check and confirm whether its correct or not

Comment: It would've been nice if you edited your data so that we can actually see what's in a column - i.e. remove the tabs and make the columns align properly.

Comment: Look up the MERGE statement; I think it is available in later versions of MS SQL Server.